# Apply distribution from all columns in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, distribution

I am trying to `plot` a `multivariate` `distribution` that is produced from `multiple` `xy` `coordinates`.

The `code` below aims to get each coordinate and apply it with a radius (`[_Rad]`). The `COV` `matrix` is then adjusted by `scaling` factor (`[_Scaling]`) to expand the radius in `x-direction` and contract in `y-direction`. The direction of this is measured by the `rotation` `angle` (`[_Rotation]`).

The output is expressed as a `probability` function, which represents the influence of each groups coordinates over a certain space.

Although, at present I can only get the `code` to apply this to the last set of `coordinates` in the `df`. So using the input below, only `A3_X, A3_Y` is working. `A1_X, A1_Y, A2_X, A2_Y` and `B1_X, B1_Y, B2_X, B2_Y`. Please see attached figure for a visual representation.

**Note: Apologies for the long `df`. It was the only way to replicate my `dataset`.**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as sts

def rot(theta):
    theta = np.deg2rad(theta)
    return np.array([
        [np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)],
        [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]
    ])

def getcov(radius=1, scale=1, theta=0):
    cov = np.array([
        [radius*(scale + 1), 0],
        [0, radius/(scale + 1)]
    ])

    r = rot(theta)
    return r @ cov @ r.T

def datalimits(*data, pad=.15):
    dmin,dmax = min(d.values.min() for d in data), max(d.values.max() for d in data)
    spad = pad*(dmax - dmin)
    return dmin - spad, dmax + spad

d = ({
    'Time' : [1],       
    'A1_Y' : [5883.102906],                 
    'A1_X' : [3321.527705], 
    'A2_Y' : [5898.467202],                 
    'A2_X' : [3328.331657],
    'A3_Y' : [5886.270552],                 
    'A3_X' : [3366.777169],                 
    'B1_Y' : [5897.925245],                 
    'B1_X' : [3297.143092], 
    'B2_Y' : [5905.137781],                 
    'B2_X' : [3321.167842],
    'B3_Y' : [5888.291025],                 
    'B3_X' : [3347.263205],                                                              
    'A1_Radius' : [10.3375199],  
    'A2_Radius' : [10.0171423], 
    'A3_Radius' : [11.42129333],                                   
    'B1_Radius' : [18.69514267],  
    'B2_Radius' : [10.65877044], 
    'B3_Radius' : [9.947025444],                       
    'A1_Scaling' : [0.0716513620],
    'A2_Scaling' : [0.0056262380], 
    'A3_Scaling' : [0.0677243260,],                                 
    'B1_Scaling' : [0.0364290850],
    'B2_Scaling' : [0.0585827450],   
    'B3_Scaling' : [0.0432806750],                                     
    'A1_Rotation' : [20.58078926], 
    'A2_Rotation' : [173.5056346],   
    'A3_Rotation' : [36.23648405],                               
    'B1_Rotation' : [79.81849817],    
    'B2_Rotation' : [132.2437404],                       
    'B3_Rotation' : [44.28198078],                                
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

A_Y = df[df.columns[1::2][:3]]
A_X = df[df.columns[2::2][:3]]

B_Y = df[df.columns[7::2][:3]]
B_X = df[df.columns[8::2][:3]]   

A_Radius = df[df.columns[13:16]] 
B_Radius = df[df.columns[16:19]]

A_Scaling = df[df.columns[19:22]] 
B_Scaling = df[df.columns[22:25]] 

A_Rotation = df[df.columns[25:28]] 
B_Rotation = df[df.columns[28:31]]

limitpad = .5
clevels = 5
cflevels = 50

xmin,xmax = datalimits(A_X, B_X, pad=limitpad)
ymin,ymax = datalimits(A_Y, B_Y, pad=limitpad)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(xmin, xmax), np.linspace(ymin, ymax))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax = plt.gca()

Zs = []
for l,color in zip('AB', ('red', 'blue')):
    ax.plot(A_X.iloc[0], A_Y.iloc[0], '.', c='red', ms=10, label=l, alpha = 0.6)
    ax.plot(B_X.iloc[0], B_Y.iloc[0], '.', c='blue', ms=10, label=l, alpha = 0.6) 

    Zrows = []
    for _,row in df.iterrows():
        for i in [1,2,3]:
            x,y = row['{}{}_X'.format(l,i)], row['{}{}_Y'.format(l,i)]

        cov = getcov(radius=row['{}{}_Radius'.format(l,i)],scale=row['{}{}_Scaling'.format(l,i)], theta=row['{}{}_Rotation'.format(l,i)])
        mnorm = sts.multivariate_normal([x, y], cov)
        Z = mnorm.pdf(np.stack([X, Y], 2))
        Zrows.append(Z)

    Zs.append(np.sum(Zrows, axis=0))

Z = Zs[0] - Zs[1]

normZ = Z - Z.min()
normZ = normZ/normZ.max()

cs = ax.contour(X, Y, normZ, levels=clevels, colors='w', alpha=.5)
ax.clabel(cs, fmt='%2.1f', colors='w')#, fontsize=14)

cfs = ax.contourf(X, Y, normZ, levels=cflevels, cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=1)

cbar = fig.colorbar(cfs, ax=ax)
cbar.set_ticks([0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1])
```

As you can see below. The `code` is only applying to `A3_X, A3_Y` and `B3_X, B3_Y`.

**It's not applying to coordinates `A1_X, A1_Y, A2_X, A2_Y` and `B1_X, B1_Y, B2_X, B2_Y`.**

[image]

Comment: @Parfait, apologies, I'll edit the question. The undesired `output` is that the code is only applied to one set of `coordinates` `(A3 and B3)`. Whereas, I want it to be applied to every set of coordinates `(A1-A2, B1-B2)`

Comment: What are the other coordinates? I see 12 values for A#_x and B#_y series and if paired up corresponds to the 6 points included in plot.

Comment: @Parfait, I've amended the question. Is it clearer? For the 6 points in the `plot`, `A3_X A3_Y` and `B3_X B3_Y` are the ones that have the radius applied. `A1_X A1_Y, A2_X A2_Y` and `B1_X B1_Y, B2_X B2_Y` have not been effectively applied.

Comment: This is obviously a follow up from your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53368263/425458). I can help you fix the code, but the part I'm still unclear about is what your z axis is supposed to represent, and thus how it should be normalized. It seems like you might be a little fuzzy about the definition of what a probability is (or at least aren't describing what your want clearly). Is z supposed to be the probability of group A having influence at a particular xy point?

Comment: @tel, I agree I was a little unclear previously. You've nailed it though. `Z` is the `probability` of a group (this could be any group) having influence over a particular `xy point`. As I understand it, this is the current output is it not? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in the way that you're iterating over the point data. The way that you have your dataframe organized makes it hard to figure out the appropriate way to iterate over the data, and makes it easy to run into errors of the kind you're getting. It would be better if your `df` was organized such that you could easily iterate over the subsets of your data representing each group `A` and `B` at each time. If you split out the times from your data dictionary `d`, here's how you can construct an easier to work with `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

time = [1]
d = ({
    'A1_Y' : [5883.102906],                 
    'A1_X' : [3321.527705], 
    'A2_Y' : [5898.467202],                 
    'A2_X' : [3328.331657],
    'A3_Y' : [5886.270552],                 
    'A3_X' : [3366.777169],                 
    'B1_Y' : [5897.925245],                 
    'B1_X' : [3297.143092], 
    'B2_Y' : [5905.137781],                 
    'B2_X' : [3321.167842],
    'B3_Y' : [5888.291025],                 
    'B3_X' : [3347.263205],                                                              
    'A1_Radius' : [10.3375199],  
    'A2_Radius' : [10.0171423], 
    'A3_Radius' : [11.42129333],                                   
    'B1_Radius' : [18.69514267],  
    'B2_Radius' : [10.65877044], 
    'B3_Radius' : [9.947025444],                       
    'A1_Scaling' : [0.0716513620],
    'A2_Scaling' : [0.0056262380], 
    'A3_Scaling' : [0.0677243260,],                                 
    'B1_Scaling' : [0.0364290850],
    'B2_Scaling' : [0.0585827450],   
    'B3_Scaling' : [0.0432806750],                                     
    'A1_Rotation' : [20.58078926], 
    'A2_Rotation' : [173.5056346],   
    'A3_Rotation' : [36.23648405],                               
    'B1_Rotation' : [79.81849817],    
    'B2_Rotation' : [132.2437404],                       
    'B3_Rotation' : [44.28198078],                                
     })

# a list of tuples of the form ((time, group_id, point_id, value_label), value)
tuples = [((t, k.split('_')[0][0], int(k.split('_')[0][1]), k.split('_')[1]), v[i]) for k,v in d.items() for i,t in enumerate(time)]

df = pd.Series(dict(tuples)).unstack(-1)
df.index.names = ['time', 'group', 'id']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  Radius    Rotation   Scaling            X            Y
time group id                                                           
1    A     1   10.337520   20.580789  0.071651  3321.527705  5883.102906
           2   10.017142  173.505635  0.005626  3328.331657  5898.467202
           3   11.421293   36.236484  0.067724  3366.777169  5886.270552
     B     1   18.695143   79.818498  0.036429  3297.143092  5897.925245
           2   10.658770  132.243740  0.058583  3321.167842  5905.137781
           3    9.947025   44.281981  0.043281  3347.263205  5888.291025
```

This will make it much easier to iterate over the subsets in your data. Here's how you would iterate over the sub-dataframes for each group at each timepoint:

```
for time, tdf in df.groupby('time'):
    for group, gdf in tdf.groupby('group'):
        ...
```

Here's an updated version of [my code from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452434/425458) that uses this better-organized dataframe to create the plot you want at every time point:

```
for time,subdf in df.groupby('time'):
    plotmvs(subdf)
```

Output:

[image]

Here's the complete code of the above `plotmvs` function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as sts

def datalimits(*data, pad=.15):
    dmin,dmax = min(d.min() for d in data), max(d.max() for d in data)
    spad = pad*(dmax - dmin)
    return dmin - spad, dmax + spad

def rot(theta):
    theta = np.deg2rad(theta)
    return np.array([
        [np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)],
        [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]
    ])

def getcov(radius=1, scale=1, theta=0):
    cov = np.array([
        [radius*(scale + 1), 0],
        [0, radius/(scale + 1)]
    ])

    r = rot(theta)
    return r @ cov @ r.T

def mvpdf(x, y, xlim, ylim, radius=1, velocity=0, scale=0, theta=0):
    """Creates a grid of data that represents the PDF of a multivariate gaussian.

    x, y: The center of the returned PDF
    (xy)lim: The extent of the returned PDF
    radius: The PDF will be dilated by this factor
    scale: The PDF be stretched by a factor of (scale + 1) in the x direction, and squashed by a factor of 1/(scale + 1) in the y direction
    theta: The PDF will be rotated by this many degrees

    returns: X, Y, PDF. X and Y hold the coordinates of the PDF.
    """
    # create the coordinate grids
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(*xlim), np.linspace(*ylim))

    # stack them into the format expected by the multivariate pdf
    XY = np.stack([X, Y], 2)

    # displace xy by half the velocity
    x,y = rot(theta) @ (velocity/2, 0) + (x, y)

    # get the covariance matrix with the appropriate transforms
    cov = getcov(radius=radius, scale=scale, theta=theta)

    # generate the data grid that represents the PDF
    PDF = sts.multivariate_normal([x, y], cov).pdf(XY)

    return X, Y, PDF

def mvpdfs(xs, ys, xlim, ylim, radius=None, velocity=None, scale=None, theta=None):
    PDFs = []
    for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(xs,ys)):
        kwargs = {
            'radius': radius[i] if radius is not None else 1,
            'velocity': velocity[i] if velocity is not None else 0,
            'scale': scale[i] if scale is not None else 0,
            'theta': theta[i] if theta is not None else 0,
            'xlim': xlim,
            'ylim': ylim
        }
        X, Y, PDF = mvpdf(x, y, **kwargs)
        PDFs.append(PDF)

    return X, Y, np.sum(PDFs, axis=0)

def plotmvs(df, xlim=None, ylim=None, fig=None, ax=None):
    """Plot an xy point with an appropriately tranformed 2D gaussian around it.
    Also plots other related data like the reference point.
    """
    if xlim is None: xlim = datalimits(df['X'])
    if ylim is None: ylim = datalimits(df['Y'])

    if fig is None:
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
        ax = fig.gca()
    elif ax is None:
        ax = fig.gca()

    PDFs = []
    for (group,gdf),color in zip(df.groupby('group'), ('red', 'blue')):
        # plot the xy points of each group
        ax.plot(*gdf[['X','Y']].values.T, '.', c=color)

        # fetch the PDFs of the 2D gaussian for each group
        kwargs = {
            'radius': gdf['Radius'].values if 'Radius' in gdf else None,
            'velocity': gdf['Velocity'].values if 'Velocity' in gdf else None,
            'scale': gdf['Scaling'].values if 'Scaling' in gdf else None,
            'theta': gdf['Rotation'].values if 'Rotation' in gdf else None,
            'xlim': xlim,
            'ylim': ylim
        }
        X, Y, PDF = mvpdfs(gdf['X'].values, gdf['Y'].values, **kwargs)
        PDFs.append(PDF)

    # create the PDF for all points from the difference of the sums of the 2D Gaussians from group A and group B
    PDF = PDFs[0] - PDFs[1]

    # normalize PDF by shifting and scaling, so that the smallest value is 0 and the largest is 1
    normPDF = PDF - PDF.min()
    normPDF = normPDF/normPDF.max()

    # plot and label the contour lines of the 2D gaussian
    cs = ax.contour(X, Y, normPDF, levels=6, colors='w', alpha=.5)
    ax.clabel(cs, fmt='%.3f', fontsize=12)

    # plot the filled contours of the 2D gaussian. Set levels high for smooth contours
    cfs = ax.contourf(X, Y, normPDF, levels=50, cmap='viridis')

    # create the colorbar and ensure that it goes from 0 -> 1
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.1)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(cfs, ax=ax, cax=cax)
    cbar.set_ticks([0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1])

    # ensure that x vs y scaling doesn't disrupt the transforms applied to the 2D gaussian
    ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')

    return fig, ax
```

Comment: thank you for this. If I wanted to include 15 separate `points`, is that ok? Also I'd like to adjust the `x-y axes limits`. I want to span `200m in the x-direction` and `150m in the y-direction` if possible. Will this disrupt the transformation?

Comment: If you add each point in exactly the same way as your first 3, it should be fine. Beware that the code used to assemble the `tuples` list is dependent upon the current format/naming conventions used in `d`.

Comment: You can set the limits to whatever you want by passing them into the `plotmvs` function, eg `plotmvs(df, xlim=(xlow, xhigh), ylim=(ylow, yhigh))`. The `ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')` line at the end of `plotmvs` tells Matplotlib to adjust the figure size so that X and Y values are drawn at the same scale, preserving the appearance of the transformations. Passing your own limits in won't affect that. Also, I don't know what you mean by `m` in `200m`.

Comment: As in set the `xlim` to span 200m. So I would adjust this `plot` to be `ax.set_xlim(3200,3400)`. If that makes sense? i just wasn't sure if it affected the transformation itself.

Comment: Also, I just wanted to confirm one last thing. I set the `df` up like I did because I'l eventuallyl want to `iterate` through each `row` to create a new `output`, which will be transformed into an `animation`. If I set the `df` up as per your example, will that generate issues if I want to apply your `code` to each `row` to create an `animation`?

Comment: Iterating over the time index of the `df` I set up will be equivalent to iterating over the rows of your original dataframe. You could set up a loop that iterates over the time index with `for time, tdf in df.groupby('time'):`

Comment: I've been playing around with your code. Specifically, the `PDF = PDFs[0] - PDFs[1]` function. I'm hoping to peg or set the contour that isn't influenced by the scatter to display a fixed value and therefore colour. This should hopefully be 0.5. I've included this as a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55118531/set-or-peg-bivariate-distribution-values-using-matplotlib. Brilliant code.

Answer (score 1):

Simply adjust indentation especially with middle inner nested `for` loop and reset *Zrows* list when iterating across data frame rows. See comments in code for specific changes:

```
...

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    # MOVE ZROWS INSIDE
    Zrows = []
    for i in [1,2,3]:
        x,y = row['{}{}_X'.format(l,i)], row['{}{}_Y'.format(l,i)]

        # INDENT cov AND LATER CALCS TO RUN ACROSS ALL 1,2,3
        cov = getcov(radius=row['{}{}_Radius'.format(l,i)],
                     scale=row['{}{}_Scaling'.format(l,i)], 
                     theta=row['{}{}_Rotation'.format(l,i)])

        mnorm = sts.multivariate_normal([x, y], cov)
        Z = mnorm.pdf(np.stack([X, Y], 2))

        # APPEND TO BE CLEANED OUT WITH EACH ROW
        Zrows.append(Z)

    Zs.append(np.sum(Zrows, axis=0))

...
```

[image: Plot Output]

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on in this code. A small thing I noticed was that it looks like you are not using the `df.columns` indexing correctly. If you look at `A_Y` the output is:

```
    A1_Rotation    A1_X        A2_Radius
0   20.580789     3321.527705  10.017142
```

I think you are mixing columns. Maybe use `df[['A1_Y', 'A2_Y', 'A3_Y']]` to get the exact columns or just put all the A_Y values into a single column.

Comment: It returns the correct columns for me @slayer? If it was wrong I'm not sure the code would work at all. Let alone the last coordinate. Ive tried your method nonetheless and it's still the same